# Google APP SCRIPT. REMOVE folder from shared with me if user is member of main shared drive folder

Tags: permissions, google-drive-api, user-permissions, google-drive-shared-drive

Situation:
I have shared drive folder which has inside more folders. Some users are the member of main shared drive folder and can see those folders through personal account and some folders are specifically shared with members (users) into shared with me section. To set permission to share certain folders into shared with me section for certain users is ok, but the **MAIN PROBLEM** is when I want to remove folder from user shared with me section, because user is a member of shared drive folder..

**IF THE USER IS A MEMBER OF SHARED DRIVE FOLDER BUT HAS SOME FOLDERS SHARED WITH HIM AND LATER THE IDEA IS REMOVE THOSE FOLDERS FROM SHARED WITH ME SECTION, HOW TO DO THAT? **
*Using app script.

I tried some different solutions, but it didn't remove from shared with me section.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't SHOUT AT US. If you need to emphasize something you can [do it with Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).